# Performance difference in two SQL queries

Tags: sql, oracle

This is simplified version of two views:

```
viewA is select * from myTable;
viewB is select * from viewA;
```

Is there any performance difference between selecting from viewA directly and selecting from viewB because selecting from viewB has another layer which is viewA?

Comment: Run 'explain plan' for the two queries and compare the result.

Comment: I don't *know* the answer.  But it is quite possible that they would behave differently under certain circumstances.  A view is compiled, and that compiled form is available to the query.  This can result in a different execution plan from compiling the code directly into the query.

Comment: The query planner *should* be smart enough to "stitch everything together" (i.e. re-plan the entire query in full context as deemed necessary), but only looking at the actual plan will say "for certain". There might gremlins with cached plans and whatnot - is sometimes in SQL Server, anyway :>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW  "VIEWA" ("TITLE", "VALUE1", "VALUE2", "ID") AS 
  select "TITLE","VALUE1","VALUE2","ID" from dati
/
​CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW  "VIEWB" ("TITLE", "VALUE1", "VALUE2", "ID") AS 
  select "TITLE","VALUE1","VALUE2","ID" from viewa
/
```

​Explain plan for select * from viewA

```
Operation           Options         Object  Rows    Time    Cost    Bytes   Filter          Access
                                                                            Predicates *    Predicates
SELECT STATEMENT                            4       1       3       268      
TABLE ACCESS        STORAGE FULL    DATI    4       1       3       268
```

Explain plan for select * from viewB

```
Operation           Options         Object  Rows    Time    Cost    Bytes   Filter          Access
                                                                            Predicates *    Predicates
SELECT STATEMENT                            4       1       3       268      
TABLE ACCESS        STORAGE FULL    DATI    4       1       3       268
```

My answer would have to be: no, there is not any performance difference.